# Group Objects based on field value Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, grouping

I receive an array of documents from Firebase Firestore (Offers). I have a field that contains the value of the section the item should be grouped by. I'd like to group all the items based on that field value then place them into a separate sections struct. I.e. if the objects have the key value pair of `["section": "featured"]` a group will be created with all the objects with "featured" as the section.

Here is my Offer struct:

```
struct Offer: Codable, Hashable {
    var documentID: String? = nil
    let title: String
    let subTitle: String
    let section: String
}
```

Here is my Section struct:

```
struct Section: Decodable, Hashable {
    let title: String
    let subTitle: String?
    let offers: [Offer]
}
```

The result I'm after is the following, a Section for each of the "section" values, here's a snapshot of my data;

```
[
  {
    "title": "Here's the title",
    "subTitle": "Here's the subTitle",
    "section": "featured"
  },
  {
    "title": "Here's the title",
    "subTitle": "Here's the subTitle",
    "section": "featured"
  },
  {
    "title": "Here's the title",
    "subTitle": "Here's the subTitle",
    "section": "popular"
  },
  {
    "title": "Here's the title",
    "subTitle": "Here's the subTitle",
    "section": "latest"
  }
]
```

So my result should return 3 sections 2 items in featured and 1 item in popular and latest.

Comment: Where do the `title` and `subtitle` of a section come from? Where do the offers come from?  What does your input data look like?

Comment: the title will be the name of the section. SubTitle will be optional. Should I be using an Enum?

Comment: No, an enum is set at compile time, you have dynamic content

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Dictionary(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init)

```
let offersBySection = Dictionary(grouping: offers, by: \.section)
```

Answer (score -2):

I've solved this with the following 2 methods;

```
func makeSection(offer: Offer) -> String {
    return offer.section
}

fileprivate func createSections(from offers: [Offer]) {
    let groups = Dictionary(grouping: offers) { (offer) in
        return makeSection(offer: offer)
    }
    self.sections = groups.map { (key, values) in
        return Section(title: key, offers: values)
    }
}
```

I then call this function when I receive the data.

```
func readData() {
        let query = firestoreService.reference(to: .offers)
        firestoreService.read(from: query, returning: Offer.self) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            case .success(let data):
                self.createSections(from: data)
                self.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```